# Why is Plotly.newPlot not recognized as a function in JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, plotly, webstorm

When using Plotly.js in WebStorm, the function `Plotly.newPlot()` is not recognized as a function and hovering over it provides the message

> Unresolved function or method newPlot()

In a previous question, the person who helped with other aspects suggested `newPlot()` wasn't a function for Plotly. I confirmed through Plotly's website (https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/) that `newPlot()` is a function.

I've only included the div and data, but that shouldn't cause a problem since the documentation from Plotly says the other variables should default to an empty list.

In addition, I've run the same code in CodePen and it works there so I believe it might have something to do with how I configured the software or an issue with how I imported Plotly.

```
    var Plotly = require('plotly')("jhharvey", "••••••••••");

    var xData = [23, 25, 12, 4]; //example data
    var yData = [1, 2, 3, 4]; //example data

    var data = [
        {
            x: xData, //x values set
            y: yData, //y values set
            type: "line" //graph type set
        }
    ];

    Plotly.newPlot("myDiv", data); //should plot data
```

Answer (score 0):

Running your code results in `TypeError: Plotly.newPlot is not a function`; searching for `newPlot` in `node_modules/plotly` doesn't return any result. This method, however, does exist in https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js so the code works in browser - but there is no way for the IDE to resolve it from  `node_modules/plotly`